# How can I switch into windows in a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

I'm trying to switch into windows and "closing" the last window. But, I want to have a shortcut (Ctrl+I) to open a new window, and if I put the `setVisible(false)` at the ActionPerformed of the (Ctrl+I), it gives me an error.

How can I hide the last window?

### Error says:

```
create method setVisible(boolean) in 
    <anonymous javax.swing.AbstractAction>
```

Here's the code:

```
jBNew.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_I, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "new");
jBNew.getActionMap().put("new", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      this.setVisible(false);(here i have the error)****
        new NextOrderWindow(codLastOrder()).setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would an `AbstractAction` be *visible*? If you want to hide the "last window", then you need a reference to the "last window".

Comment: `this` is referencing the (anonymous) instance of `AbstractAction`, which obviously, doesn't have a `setVisible` method

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)